# java.lang.module.FindException: Module com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation not found

Tags: javafx

I'm having issues launching/debugging my JavaFx app from within IntelliJ.

This message appears

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation not found, required by com.almasb.fxgl.gameplay
```

When launched from the command line, all works well.

I'm running Java 17.0.2

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Is this a `module-info` issue?

Comment: It would appear you don't have the required jackson modules on your module path.

Comment: How are you managing dependencies? Via a build tool (Maven, Gradle, etc.), or via the IDE directly? Whichever, you need to make sure you have Jackson declared as a dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jewelsea I found the solution ...

Added to the module-info file

```
requires com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation;
```

And to the pom.xml ...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Reloaded the project and works well ...